# Dúvidas com select array

Tags: javascript, html

Não tenho muito conhecimento em javascript, gostaria de saber se é possível, ao mudar um select principal, atualizar os demais para selecionar a mesma informação desse principal.

Exemplo: Vou escolher a moeda principal de uma forma de pagamento. Ao selecioná-la, gostaria que as X parcelas abaixo fossem atualizadas para também selecionar a mesma moeda:

```
<label>Moeda Principal</label>
<select id='principal' onchange='atualizar()'>
    <option value="1">Dinheiro</option>
    <option value="2">Cheque</option>
</select>

<label>Parcela 1</label>
<select name='parcela[]'>
    <option value="1">Dinheiro</option>
    <option value="2">Cheque</option>
</select>

<label>Parcela 2</label>
<select name='parcela[]'>
    <option value="1">Dinheiro</option>
    <option value="2">Cheque</option>
</select>
```

É possível?
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Olá Gisele! Já há perguntas parecidas e com boas respostas. Olha os links que coloquei em cima. Boa sorte!